# Laravel file upload: validation disk space

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload

I have a file upload validation and would like to have an error message if the disk is full.

My validation looks like this at the moment:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => [
        'required',
        'file',
        'mimes:' . $mimes,
        'max:' . config('myapp.max-file-size-kb')
    ]
], $messages);
```

I could use `max` for this but that would tell the user that the file is to large. But that is not really the problem.

Comment: Are you creating something like Google drive for a company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that should work:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => [
        'required',
        'file',
        'mimes:' . $mimes,
        'max:' . config('myapp.max-file-size-kb'),
        static function ($attribute, $file, $fail) {
            $free_space = disk_free_space( Storage::disk('uploads')->path('/') );
            if ($file->getSize() > $free_space) {
                $fail('Not enough disk space: ' . $free_space . ' bytes left.');
            }
        },
    ]
], $messages);
```

Comment: I am not sure if that really works ... PHP / Apache might cache the uploaded data somewhere, so you might need to use double space. if the uploads path is on a different volume it might work. But do you really want to tell your users how much space is left and let them to fill up your volume. Would be interested in what you use case is. Maybe you should rather limit the upload size way below free disk space and setup a monitoring by the ops team to early detect when space runs out. Or store in some unlimited S3 buckets :)

Comment: Sure, this does not make sense for some Storages like S3. In my case it is a local drive. The uploaded file is first stored by apache on the same drive then moved into position after validation (like normal upload). Yes, there is monitoring but in the end of the day monitoring fails or the human watching it was sleeping...
So I would like the user to know that the drive is full and there is nothing he can do about it. It is important for the user experience to understand what the problem is otherwise he will try 10 times and still think it is his fault :D